# Python recursion with yield and return in nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I'm trying to learn the use of yield and return in recursive function. I've a nested dictionary where I'm searching for a particular value.

When using "yield", the following function runs fine and returns the found value successfully:

```
def findvalue (value, document):
    if isinstance (document, list):
        for d in document:
            for result in findvalue(value, d):
                yield result
    if isinstance (document, dict):
        for k,v in document.items():
            if v == value:
                yield v
            elif isinstance (v, dict):
                for result in findvalue(value, v):
                    yield result
            elif isinstance (v, list):
                for d in v:
                    for result in findvalue(value, d):
                        yield result
```

I understand how generator works and why yield does what it does in above code. Now if I use the same code, but with return and put a check in there to check for empty return, I still end up with "NoneType" iteration issue because somewhere an empty result is being returned in this code:

```
def valuefind (value, document):
    if isinstance (document, list):
        for d in document:
            for result in valuefind(value, d):
                if result is not None:
                    return result          
    if isinstance (document, dict):
        for k, v in document.items():
            if v == value:
                return v
            elif isinstance (v, dict):
                for result in valuefind(value, v):
                    if result is not None:
                        return result
            elif isinstance (v, list):
                for d in value:
                    for result in valuefind(value, d):
                        if result is not None:
                            return result
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the "NoneType iteration issue"? I don't understand your problem. Please tell us what is the expected result and what actually happens for a given input. Also one of the differences between these 2 codes is that if Python doesn't reach any `return` statement (due to none of the condition being satisfied) then it will reach the end of the function and return `None`.

Comment: When a value and nested dictionary is passed to the function, the expected result is it should iterate and if it finds an instance of that value then return it to caller so that we can confirm that an instance was found in a particular nested dictionary. The "NoneType" issue is that when using "return" instead of "yield", the function is unable to iterate and stops with error "NoneType" object is not iterable. I'm trying to find out how return statement can be used  instead of yield to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can change this:

```
for result in valuefind(value, v):
                    if result is not None:
                        return result
```

To this:

```
return valuefind(value, v)
```

Comment: This works intermittently. For example, it may find the result in 10 executions or provides result in list with irrelevant values.